# AS3 /XML - Cannot dynamically access xml

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm extremely new to AS3 and seem to be over my head here.

I'm trying to get the script to pull a different .xml file as dependant on what was selected from an array generated menu on a previous scene. Though I'd wanted this to be more flexible, I'm willing to just create an 'if' statement to choose the .xml - but I'm unable to trace the variable that will change depending on the menu item selected.

Here is what I'm working with currently. It's the flexible version (I still have hope). Like I said, I'm very new to this and if you need to see more to get a better picture let me know.

```
var item_list = new Array();
var i:Number;
var total:Number;

var find_xml:XML = new XML();

// This part is what pulls from the frame that this is placed on
// The as3 script on the frame --- "page_2.load_xml("enter xml file");"
function push_array(e:Event):void{
  find_xml = XML(e.target.data);
  total = find_xml.item.length();
  for( i = 0; i < total; i++ ){
    item_list.push( { content: find_xml.item[i].content.toString() } );
  }
}

function load_xml(xml_file:String):void{
  var xml_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  xml_loader.load( new URLRequest( xml_file ) );
  xml_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, push_array);
}

//Here is where the variable holding the .xml will go
var xml_file:String = place variable with .xml file name here;
```

Thanks for any help!

----ADDED: Here is the remaining code----

```
try{
  var key_str:String;
  var value_str:String;
  var param_obj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
  for ( key_str in param_obj ){
    value_str = String( param_obj[key_str] );
    if( key_str == "xml_file" )
      xml_file = value_str;
    break;
  }
}
catch (error:Error) {}

touch_slider.load_gallery( xml_file );

import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;

var menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
var copyright:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem( "" );
var credit:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem( "" );\

menu.hideBuiltInItems();
menu.customItems.push(copyright, credit);
this.contextMenu = menu;

function visit(e:Event){
var my_link:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "" );
navigateToURL( link, "_self" );
}

function visit_bar_slider(e:Event){
var my_link:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "" );
navigateToURL( my_link, "_parent" );
}
```

Comment: SO this code loads an XML file and puts its children in an array. It looks to me. Could you explain better what is the part you are having problems with?

Comment: Could you share the code that shows how're you calling "function load_xml()" please.

Comment: If I put the .xml directly in (so it reads var xml_file:String = "my_list.xml") everything works. What I'm hoping to do is have the variable that populates "xml_file" change.

Comment: `( { content: find_xml.item[i].content.toString() } );` i'M curious about that, maybe it's something i don't know, but what is this `( { content: ` stuff here.

you may trying to do that?  `item_list.push( { "content: " + find_xml.item[i].content.toString() } );`

Comment: I'm hoping that it will grab the name for the .xml from the frame it's object is placed on (apologies in any poor terminology).

Comment: fine, so, what about that, var i:Number; var total:Number; why not integers? actually that doesn't make any problem in most cases, but sometimes makes..

Comment: you want the content in "<node>content</node>" nodes as string right?

Comment: <photos>

 <config
  auto_play="true"
  auto_play_duration="5" 
  slide_direction="left"
  tween_duration="0.5"
  tween_effect="easeInOutQuad">
 </config>
 
 <photo>
  <filename>photos/ninki.jpg</filename>
  <target>_self</target>
 </photo>
 
 <photo>
  <filename>photos/richmond_station.jpg</filename>
  <target>_parent</target>
 </photo>
 
 <photo>
  <filename>photos/quinns.jpg</filename>
  <target>_self</target>
 </photo>
 
</photos>

Answer (score 0):

Edit your xml file like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<photos>
   <config auto_play="true" auto_play_duration="5" slide_direction="left" tween_duration="0.5" tween_effect="easeInOutQuad"/>
   <photo>
      <filename>photos/ninki.jpg</filename>
      <target>_self</target>
   </photo>
   <photo>
      <filename>photos/richmond_station.jpg</filename>
      <target>_self</target>
   </photo>
</photos>
```

And use this function to pull them into an array

```
var photolinks:Array = new Array();
var phototargets:Array = new Array();

function pullXMLtoArray(xml:XML):void
{
   var auto_play = xml.config.@auto_play; //a sample for pulling settings
   var photolist:XMLList = xml.photo;
   var photo:XML;
   for each (photo in photolist)
   {
      photolinks.push(String(photo.filename));
      phototargets.push(String(photo.target));
   }
}
```

So, now, you have 2 different arrays, one for photolinks, another for phototargets...

photolinks[1] & phototargets[1] are belong to same photo node